# CentOS 7.6 install fails w. NVIDIA P620 set to offboard or auto, completes OK set to onboard

Tags: centos, system-installation, nvidia, bios, vga

Using a Supermicro server w/ an NVIDIA P620 graphics card, I try to install CentOS-7.6.1810 from DVD. I have two monitors connected, a 2560x1440 qnix via white DVD-D cable off the P620 graphics card with a miniDP-DVI adapter; and a dell 1920x1200 via blue VGA off server motherboard.

In the BIOS, under PCIe settings there is **VGA Priority**, and the choices are **onboard**, **offboard**, and **auto**.

with it set to **offboard** I can fully get through the bios settings, and through the LSI raid settings, the dvd will boot and I will get the simple black & white text menu of *Install CentOS*, *Test this media*, and *Troubleshoot*, *press e to edit*.... I can choose install and get all the way up to where you would expect [anaconda?] the graphical screen asking for language, and my monitor just stays blank at that point.

If I choose VGA Priority = auto, same as offboard.

If I choose VGA Priority = **onboard**, everything happens on the 1900x1200 VGA monitor and I can get completely through the install process and have a running system.

**My question is**, using *VGA Priority = offboard* is there a way once at that text menu where you do *Install CentOS*... and that is where it has *press e* or *press c for command prompt*, is there something special syntax I can give the installer to make it all work through the Nvidia p620 to a 2560x1440 monitor?